# Ensuring Long-Term Data Accessibility in Life Cycle Assessment (LCA) for the Building Sector: Strategies and Challenges

Tags: life-cycle-analysis

I'm currently dealing with a challenge regarding the long-term accessibility of data in Life Cycle Assessment (LCA) setups, particularly within the Building sector. One recurring concern is ensuring that our data remains usable and accessible over the next 10 to 50 years. While one solution might be to generate PDF-based reports regularly, this isn't truly digital.

I'd appreciate any advice or discussions on how to tackle this issue effectively. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Sustainable Living! Questions about LCA are on topic here, but my impression is that your question is more about sustainable data formats, is that right? 
If so, I'm not sure if that is on topic here. In any case, perhaps you could explain a bit more what your problem is?